# Submitting custom text from select box into textarea when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, select, box

Upon hitting the "post thread" button, I want it to add custom text to the textarea depending on what dropdown is selected in a select box. I have this script in the head of the newthread template but yet it still won't work upon submitting. am I doing something wrong?

```js
function setText() {
  var tasks = document.getElementById('tasks');
  var message = document.getElementById('message');
  message.value = tasks.value +  message.value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="tasks">
    <option value="texthere 1">forage</option>
    <option value="texthere 2">attack</option>
    <option value="texthere 3">defend</option>
  </select><br/>
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Post reply" onClick="setText();" tabindex="3" accesskey="s" /><br/>
  <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="20" cols="70" tabindex="2">message</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: I made you a working snippet. Please make it into a [mcve] - I assumed you had your HTML wrapped in a form. If not, then make the button a type="button"

Comment: Note you should never assign click event handlers to a submit button. Use the submit event. Also not you will not see the message since the form is submitted and the page is unloaded

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are submitting the form and setting text at the same time.
Try to use e.preventDefault(); to prevent form from submition and run your code before form submition.

take a look at this
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_textarea_value2

Answer (score 0):

First select your form then add a "submit" event listener to form and add a callback function with passing event, inside the callback function call event.preventDefault() method and your setText() function.

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setText()

})

function setText() {
  var tasks = document.getElementById('tasks');
  var message = document.getElementById('message');
  message.value = tasks.value + message.value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="tasks">
    <option value="texthere 1">forage</option>
    <option value="texthere 2">attack</option>
    <option value="texthere 3">defend</option>
  </select><br />
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Post reply" tabindex="3" accesskey="s"><br />
  <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="20" cols="70" tabindex="2">message</textarea>
</form>
```